# How to setup cucumber on top of protractor to do end to end testing?

Tags: protractor, cucumber

Need to setup cucumber framework on top of protractor to do end to end testing. Kindly provide to steps to successfully run the setup

Answer (score 1):

Steps to setup Protractor cucumber framework:

1. Install npm install --save-dev protractor-cucumber-framework
2. To implement this framework, utilize the protractor custom framework

config option:

```
exports.config = {
  // set to "custom" instead of cucumber. 
  framework: 'custom',

  // path relative to the current config file 
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework')
};
```